# MySQL/MariaDB Trigger for Taking Ran Query and Pasting into a Row

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, mariadb

So one of the projects I'm working on requires us to take every query that is ran on the server and automatically paste that query into a table inside of the database. The reason for this is so that the DBA is able to view all prior SQL Queries that have been ran on the box. Unfortunately I don't have any leeway to do this differently as the client is requiring this implementation.

Has anybody done this before or has any code that I could use that will automatically do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful!  If you do an `INSERT` for every action taken, you will need to do an `INSERT` for that `INSERT`, at which point, you will ...

That is, the first logged query will hang the server and fill up the disk!

Instead of doing the task the way it is asked, turn on the "general log" and periodically scrape what it in it into *another* machine, which does *not* have this logging turned on.

Other arguments against the task as stated...

- If a table has `TRIGGERs`, you will not be able to add another `TRIGGER`.
- If "every query" really means "every", it is impossible (with a `TRIGGER`) since you can't write a `SELECT` or `SHOW` trigger.

"as the client is requiring this implementation".  I would approach this *unreasonable* constraint by politely finding out what the *real* goal is.  He has only described is an *implementation*.

If his *goal* is some kind of audit log, then my suggestion about the general log should suffice.